# return types of ftp.storbinary() in python

Tags: python-2.7

How to check the ftp.storbinary() upload the file successfully in ftp location. I mean what is the return types of storbinary() method to identified the failure and success case.

thanks,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is Python. Python uses exceptions to indicate error conditions, not return values.

```
try:
  ftp.storbinary(...)
except ftplib.all_errors:
   ...
else:
  print "Transfer succeeded!"
```